# Memory taken by my application showing more than assigned

Tags: java, memory

I am running a java server program to which i have assigned 4096M RAM but it shows memory as below in top command .

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1512384 root      20   0   12.8g   5.3g  38912 S   3.6  11.2 245:33.64 /usr/java/jre/bin/java

it is showing residential memory as 5.3g and virtual as 12.8 , why this is so. these are higher than assigned memory of 4G

Answer (score 0):

You likely used `java -Xmx` which limits the maximum heap space for the java process. However heap is not the only memory region a JVM manages.

There is a good explanation on https://medium.com/platform-engineer/understanding-java-memory-model-1d0863f6d973

Comment: Thanks Hiran for you answer .that is quite helpful . i also want to know what is residential memory . its heap+ which memory?

Comment: The virtual memory is all memory a process occupies, parts of which may get swapped to disk. The resident set is the non-swapped part. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size